# Connected vs Separated Set in Frechet (V) Space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

From the first chapter of Sierpinski's "General Topology," discussing Frechet (*V*)Spaces:

"A set *E* is connected if and only if it satisfies the following condition *W*:

If *A* is a non-empty subset of *E* with the property that for every element of the set *A* $\cup$ *A'* $\cap$ *E* there exists a neighbourhood *U* of this element such that *U* $\cap$ *E* $\subset$ *A*, then *A* = *E*."

This confuses me because a necessary and sufficient condition for a set *E* being connected is that it doesn't possess a non-empty proper subset that is both closed and open within *E*. Condition *W* says that, in the case *E* is not connected, it contains a non-empty subset *A* that is open (because every element of *A* has a neighbourhood whose elements in *E* are contained in *A*), but I don't see how *W* prevents *B* = *E* - *A* from containing elements of *A'* $\cap$ *E* (i.e. *A* is not closed within *E*, and therefore *E* could still be connected).,

It seems like *W* only says that, if *E* isn't connected, then *A* $\cup$ *A'* $\cap$ *E* doesn't contain elements of *B'* $\cap$ *E*, where *B* = *E* - *A*. But under that condition *B* could still contain elements of *A'* $\cap$ *E*, making *W* not necessary for showing a set *E* is connected.

I'm either misreading *W*, or I have faulty logic.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain the meaning of $A+B$ and $A.B$. Probably union and intersection? If so, I suggest to write $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Made the edits

Comment: If you take a relatively closed $A$ in condition $W$, the condition says "if A is a nonempty (relatively) closed and open subset of $E$, then $A = E$". That gives you connectedness. That connection $W$ also talks about subsets of $E$ that aren't relatively closed isn't essential.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the answer. I understand how "if *A* is a nonempty (relatively) closed and open subset of *E*, then *A*=*E*" leads to connectedness, just not sure how *W* expresses that condition. All I get out of *W* is that *A* is relatively open because none of its elements are limit elements of *B*; I can't tell what logically leads to *A* being relatively closed as well.

Comment: $A\subseteq E$ is relatively closed if and only if $(A \cup A') \cap E = A$. Generally, $(A \cup A') \cap E = \overline{A}\cap E$ is the relative closure of $A$. In words, condition $W$ says "if $A$ is a nonempty subset of $E$ such that its relative closure is relatively open [and contained in $A$], then $A = E$".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your patience, I think I'm starting to get it. Is there some guaranteed $(A \cup A') \cap E$ is the relative closure of $A$ under $W$? The chapter I'm on mentions that such closures exist, but is currently operating under very general principles and not all closures are necessarily $(A \cup A')$ (for instance, how does $W$ guaranteed that limit elements of $A'$ aren't present in $B$?)

edit: I also don't understand how $W$ says the relative closure is contained in $A$